# "proper" way to pass control to a new page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I think this is more a "style" question than anything else.

I have an MVC application consisting of a main page, where the user enters search criteria, and a list page, where a list of items matching the criteria are displayed.

When the user requests the search on the main page, MainPage.cshtml has this code to call ListPageController to generate the new page:

```
var ParamString = 
  "Param1=" + Param1
  + "+Param2=" + Param2
  + "+Param3=" + Param3
  + "+Param4=" + Param4
  + "+Param5=" + Param5;
window.open(encodeURI("/ListPage/ShowList?" + ParamString), "_self");
```

Here is the code for ShowList in ListPageController.cs:

```
public ActionResult ShowList
(
  String p_Param1
, String p_Param2
, String p_Param3
, String p_Param4
, String p_Param5
)
{
    ListPageModel M = new ListPageModel;
    M.Param1 = p_Param1;
    M.Param1 = p_Param2;
    M.Param1 = p_Param3;
    M.Param1 = p_Param4;
    M.Param1 = p_Param5;
    return View("ListPage", M);
}
```

ListPage.cshtml then obtains the data through a jQuery Ajax call using the specified parameters.

Is using window.open with a string of parameters the "correct" way to do this?  If there are a large number of parameters instead of just five, wouldn't this make the URL rather large?

Or, for example, should the window open call be in ListPageController, which would be called by, say, a jQuery .post call?

Comment: If the parameters + url could potentially be longer than 2000 characters, you should create a hidden form and submit it to post to the page (if you want the result to become the new page). `.post` won't bring in the new content unless you specifically append the result of .post into the current page.

Comment: Remember the old days when you'd pass in the search term on a query string to some script with a SQL query in it? And you'd generate some table tags or something, and it'd all just work and everyone would know what was going on? I miss those days. CGI scripts, tables, SQL... you knew where you were. That was programming, kids. Now it's all models on QVC or something. Anyway. What's for dinner? Is it spaghetti night again already? Nurse! Nurse! The screens!..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on another StackExchange site: codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use jQuery at all. After all, the end result of your current implementation is reloading the page entirely from the server.

The simplest and in my opinion cleanest way to do this would be to have the search field be inside an old fashioned form with method "POST" and action "/ListPage/ShowList". No javascript needed!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use JQuery in this case. You could simply call the `ShowList` action by using [HtmlHelper.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703457%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and passing the entered parameters there. This should make things easier for you, too.